# Wrote a plugin for BitBucket API calls. Unable to find my plugin when used in master.cfg

Tags: python, buildbot

I wrote a class that wrapped BitBucket API calls. Can confirm it worked standalone, however, when I add that python class to /master/buidlbot/changes/bitbucket.py. And add this class in master/setup.py

```
 ('buildbot.changes.bitbucket', ['BitbucketPullrequestPoller', 'BitBucketBuildStatusAPIWrapper']),
```

It still complains plugin not found.  I also used the /master/bin/buildbot executable as well. I am assuming the compiled buildbot executable should just point to the python script, so I am assuming I don't need to recompile buildbot, but at the same time I am not sure why it isn't working. Any helps will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run

```
python <path to buildbot repo>/master/setup.py build
python <path to buildbot repo>/master/setup.py install
```